# Rows after multicolumn rows appear wider in longtable, how can I solve it?

Tags: color, longtable, colortbl

I experience this issue where the rows in a `longtable` after `\multicolumn{1}{r}{Some text}` are contracted:

**Problem:**

Here is an example *holding all packages I currently use*:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx,csquotes}
\usepackage{pdfpages,enumitem,xcolor,sidenotes,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,multicol,colortbl,url,pbox,pifont}

\begin{document}
        \begin{longtable}{@{}rl@{}}
            \rowcolor{tablehead}
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{{\color{tabletxt}
                     \textbf{A header which is multicolumn}}}
            \\ \addlinespace[2mm]
            \rowcolor{tableodd}
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text}
            &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Website}
            \\ \addlinespace[-1mm]
                \midrule \addlinespace[2mm]
                % HEADER END
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
            \rowcolor{tableodd} Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
            \rowcolor{tableodd} Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
            \rowcolor{tableodd} Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
            \rowcolor{tableodd} Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
            \rowcolor{tableodd} Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
        \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in the following table (Note the difference in width):

[image: table with issue]

**One Solution:**

While using `\multicolumn{}{}{}` in all cells, this solves the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{geometry,graphicx,csquotes}
\usepackage{pdfpages,enumitem,xcolor,sidenotes,fancyhdr}
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,multicol,colortbl,url,pbox,pifont}

\begin{document}
        \begin{longtable}{@{}rl@{}}
            \rowcolor{tablehead}
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{{\color{tabletxt}
                    \textbf{A header which is multicolumn}}}
            \\ \addlinespace[2mm]
            \rowcolor{tableodd}
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{Multicolumn text}
            &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Multicolumn website}
            \\ \addlinespace[-1mm]
                \midrule \addlinespace[2mm]
                % HEADER END
            \multicolumn{1}{r}{Some Text}
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\url{http://www.example.com/example}} \\
            \rowcolor{tableodd}
                \multicolumn{1}{r}{Some Text}
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\url{http://www.example.com/example}} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{r}{Some Text}
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\url{http://www.example.com/example}} \\
            \rowcolor{tableodd}
                \multicolumn{1}{r}{Some Text}
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\url{http://www.example.com/example}} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{r}{Some Text}
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\url{http://www.example.com/example}} \\
            \rowcolor{tableodd}
                \multicolumn{1}{r}{Some Text}
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\url{http://www.example.com/example}} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{r}{Some Text}
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\url{http://www.example.com/example}} \\
            \rowcolor{tableodd}
                \multicolumn{1}{r}{Some Text}
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\url{http://www.example.com/example}} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{r}{Some Text}
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\url{http://www.example.com/example}} \\
            \rowcolor{tableodd}
                \multicolumn{1}{r}{Some Text}
                & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\url{http://www.example.com/example}} \\
        \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Which resolves to the following table:

[image]

**Further reading**

In section 4 "Multicolumn entries" of the [longtable](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) documentation, David Carlisle describes the `\kill` and `\setlongtables` commands. But it is not clear to me how these solve the issues. I've tried to use kill on an empty row on top, even on a multicolumn spanning both columns.

Even after several passes, I cannot seem to get the rows in line, so to speak.
I firmly believe there is a better option than using multicolumn in every cell.

Any ideas?

Comment: in column definition remove `@{}` ...

Comment: Off-topic: It's poor practice to load the `xcolor` and  `colortbl` packages independently. If both packages are needed, one should issue the instruction `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` to optimize the interoperability between the two packages.

Comment: @zarko, I cannot believe I missed that!

Comment: @mico, by doing so, I get a option clash warning.

Comment: @OleAnders - Do you still load the `xcolor`and/or `colortbl` packages individually? As I tried to explain in my earlier comment, the main point of providing the instruction `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` is to make loading the packages individually unnecessary. If you don't believe me, see the code in @Zarko's answer...

Comment: @mico - I managed to resolve, by loading all packages individually (not grouping them as in my example), and then removing colortbl altogether.

Comment: @OleAnders - Indeed, if the `xcolor` package is loaded with the option `table`, one should *not* load the `colortbl` package separately as well.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing your posting to remove all references to the `multicol` package, as it is neither involved in the issue you've raised nor even used in your code.

Comment: You know, @mico, I've always used multicol as if that was what enabled `\multicolumn`.. I think I got that from my teacher sometime ago - and never looked back.

**regarding** the xcolor comment, what I meant was, that when I only pulled out xcolor from the group and added `[table]`, then removed `colortbl`; i got the option clash error. But after I _ungrouped_ all packages the issue was gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cause of your problem is feature of [`colortbl`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/colortbl/colortbl.pdf) package, see explanation  in section 1 and 2 in the package documentation.

The simplest solution is not to use `@{}` in definition of [`longtable`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) columns: instead of `\begin{longtable}{@{}rl@{}}` you should use only `\begin{longtable}{rl}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
        \begin{longtable}{rl}
            \rowcolor{gray}
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{{\color{white}
                    \scshape \textbf{A header which is multicolumn}}}
            \\ \addlinespace[2mm]
            \rowcolor{gray!30}
                \multicolumn{1}{c}{Text}
            &
            \multicolumn{1}{c}{Website}
            \\ \addlinespace[-1mm]
                \midrule \addlinespace[2mm]
                % HEADER END
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
            \rowcolor{gray!30} Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
            \rowcolor{gray!30} Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
            \rowcolor{gray!30} Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
            \rowcolor{gray!30} Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
            \rowcolor{gray!30} Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
                Some text & \url{http://www.example.com/example} \\
        \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

**Note:** as noted *Mico* in his comment, Computer Modern fonts doesn't feature a bold small caps font shape/face.

Comment: Don't enclose a `longtable` environment in a `center` environment. Also, it may be worth pointing out that Computer Modern doesn't feature a bold smallcaps font shape/face.

Comment: @Mico, 
I know that the `longtable` is centered in itself. I simple forgot to remove `\begin{center} ...\end{center}˙` ... corrected now. Regarding used font, I didn't give any attention to this issue. My bed :)